# Get the time of request in ASP.NET core 2.1

Tags: asp.net-core

I need to get the time of the request to version some database records and other records that will be created throughout the request.

I can't use DateTime now because I want the same time to be accessible throughout the request.

I can't seem to find anything in the HTTPContext class to help me.

Comment: Why can't you use a datetime variable say requestTime =  DateTime.Now() before you create the request and use requestTime thoughout the request while you version the records?

Comment: You can use `DateTime.Now` add it to `HttpContext.Items` in your middleware or somewhere else.

Comment: You can also use `HttpContext.Features` if I'm not wrong.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

## Using HttpContext.Features and your HTTP request pipeline middleware

```cs
public interface IHttpRequestTimeFeature
{
    DateTime RequestTime { get; }
}

public class HttpRequestTimeFeature : IHttpRequestTimeFeature
{
    public DateTime RequestTime { get; }    

    public HttpRequestTimeFeature()
    {
        RequestTime = DateTime.Now;
    }
}

// You don't need a separate class for this
public class RequestTimeMiddleware
{
    private readonly RequestDelegate _next;

    public RequestTimeMiddleware(RequestDelegate next)
    {
        _next = next;
    }

    public Task InvokeAsync(HttpContext context)
    {
        var httpRequestTimeFeature = new HttpRequestTimeFeature();
        context.Features.Set<IHttpRequestTimeFeature>(httpRequestTimeFeature);

        // Call the next delegate/middleware in the pipeline
        return this._next(context);
    }
}
```

You have to add this middleware in your `Startup.Configure`:

`app.UseMiddleware<RequestTimeMiddleware>();`

You can access request time like:

```cs
var httpRequestTimeFeature = HttpContext.Features.Get<IHttpRequestTimeFeature>();
if (httpRequestTimeFeature != null)
{
    var requestTime = httpRequestTimeFeature.RequestTime;
}
```

## Using HttpContext.Items

`HttpContext.Items["RequestTime"] = DateTime.Now;`

You can also store it in your scoped service(`services.AddScoped<YourService>()`) if I'm not wrong, that will be valid through the entire request.

I'm not aware if there's such thing as request time built-in into ASP.NET Core though.

You can also set this in MVC filters but I think this is more valid in the lower level (HTTP request pipeline).

Comment: Thanks for answering.  This looks sensible and I'll try to implement it.  I'm surprised there is no timestamp built in.

Comment: @ChristopherEdwards you should ask on the official repo, you might get a better response from someone who was working on HTTP stuff

Comment: @ChristopherEdwards there's something like https://github.com/aspnet/HttpAbstractions/blob/87cd79d6fc54bb4abf07c1e380cd7a9498a78612/src/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http/Features/HttpRequestIdentifierFeature.cs

Comment: It seems like it's a time but base32 encoded, the time is encapsulated in  `private static long _requestId`. This should give you unique request id.

Comment: `HttpContext.TraceIdentifier` seems like the only thing ASP.NET Core exposes publicly.

Comment: @ChristopherEdwards it was available in asp.net MVC but it was not ported to core.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.httpcontext.timestamp?view=netframework-4.8